# sql query to get 2 values in a single field

Tags: sql

Suppose I am having table A with 3 fields
Name, dob,age

sara   30-sep-1990  20

i need to get an output from select query as

sara,{30-sep-1990:20}

ie 2 values in a single field with braces seperated by colon

Answer (score 1):

Concatenation depends on your DBMS :

```
MySQL: CONCAT()
Oracle: CONCAT(), ||
SQL Server: +
```

Example MySQL :

```
Select Name, CONCAT('{', dob, ':', age, '}')
From A
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show schema info (table, column names) or state which database you're using.
For oracle:

```
select '{'||dob||':'||age||'}' from tablename;
```

For anything else see your database documentation.
See the faq: https://stackoverflow.com/faq